# Keycloak 3.4.3 and springboot 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

Hi,  I am trying to use single-sign on with keycloak and springboot 2 app

I got local keycloak setup realm and client.

I followed this example : [spring-boot-keycloak-tutorial](https://github.com/sebastienblanc/spring-boot-keycloak-tutorial)

This works fine, my issue is that I want to implement single sign on. Which means I don't want the user to login using keycloak login page.

If the users are logged in to the network (using Windows machine), and try to access the page, then they should be able to access the application without login because they are valid network users.

I don't seem to find an example on how to setup SSO and pass the credentials directly from windows to keycloak

Comment: Keycloak actually is so powerful, that difficult to start with :) What I did, I cloned existing project and make it working on my local machine, for example: https://github.com/callicoder/spring-security-react-ant-design-polls-app . After I did removed all unnecessary from there, and updated Spring/Whatever version to match my existing project. After try to copy all necessary to your project and should work. Took me couple of weeks to become familiar with Keycloak. Unless you know better way

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your realm to use **Kerberos** user federation. This will enable SSO using the active directory.
See [the official example page](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/kerberos)
You then need to make sure that your browser to support [the SSO](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_10.0.0/admin/conf_configuringwebclientbrowsersforwindowssinglesigno_t.html).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the keycloak-spring-boot-adapter does not work for spring boot 2.0+

I changed my spring version to 1.5.3 instead of 2.0.5 and this solved the problem.

I am not sure if there is an alternative for spring boot 2.0